# Beracha on hallel on in a shul where they dont make a beracha

Tags: minhag, blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, hallel

If an ashkenazi davens in a shul where the minhag is not to make a beracha on half hallel on rosh chodesh or the last 6 days of pesach, should they still make a beracha on hallel?